# React - Mutating the state argument from setSate

Tags: reactjs

I know we are not supposed to mutate a state object directly. Does this apply to the state object available in the call back of `setState`. I am looking to avoid using the spread operator too much. For example, can we do the following

```
setState(prevState => {
    prevState.count += 1;
    prevState.data.list[0].item.prop = 34;
    return prevState;
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid spread operator ? It is a good practice to not to manipulate original data. It is always a good idea to create at least a shallow copy of the original data before do modifications on them.

Comment: Consider [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dust-w1xs0?file=/src/App.js) example. You'll see that the state object manipulation is not reflected. This is because react *thinks* nothing changed, because you returned the same (`===`) state as before. So yeah, what Dilshan said. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi That was really helpful. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always make copies from objects you modify to update state, otherwise you will face bugs in your application since you have the same reference. Each part of state you modify you should make a copy, which in really nested states could be difficult.

One thing advisable is to flat your state if you can. This way you avoid really nested states, which would lead to multiple copies and prone to error. Your example, it looks you could have 2 different states `count` and `items`:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [items, setItems] = useState(dataItems);

// some update state function logic call
setCount(count => ++count);
setItems(items => {
    const nextItems = [...items]; // new arrray copy
    nextItems[0] = { ...nextItems[0], prop: 34}; // new copy obj
    return nextItems;
});
```

otherwise your state update would look like:

```
setState(prevState => {
    const nextState = { ...prevState }
    nextState.count += 1;
    nextState.data = { ...nextState.data }
    nextState.data.list = [ ...nextData.data.list ]
    const item = nextState.data.list[0]
    nextState.data.list[0].item = { ...nextState.data.list[0].item , prop: 34 };
    return nextState;
});
```

Comment: Using shallow copy on prevState seems to be working just fine for me. Is applying the spread operator on the inner objects neccessary? Will avoiding them cause any problems down the line?

Comment: it's considered best practice, there are few pitfalls you could face eventually that can lead to bugs. though as you say you could get away with a shallow copy with no problems most of the time.